# pretty much lost : self.parent.parent.__class__

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I needed to serialize a self referencing hierarchy

```
class Systm(models.Model):
    ...
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank = True, null = True, related_name="children")
```

and I was able to achieve that with the following code:

```
class RecursiveField(serializers.Serializer):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        serializer = self.parent.parent.__class__(value, context=self.context)
        return serializer.data

class SystmSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = RecursiveField(many = True, read_only = True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Systm
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'type', 'children')
```

It works and everything is bright except that all I did was to copy and paste the code but no idea how it works and why it works. It is pretty annoying and I want to understand it.
I put '`print`' commands into '`to_representation(...)`' but still not clear. I learnt that that there is recursion when the '`self.parent.parent.__class__(value, context=self.context)`' is executed but not sure why.
I'd be really grateful if somebody could explain it to me.

Thanks,
V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This basically works by getting the top serializer class and instanciating it to return the serialized value of a child. The `parent` attribute of a serializer (or field) is the serializer instance that declared this as a field.

`self.parent` is the List Serializer implicitly created when declaring `many=True` (see [ListSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer)).
`self.parent.parent` is the `SystmSerializer` instance.

My guess is that this code only works because the recursive field has been declared with `many=True`. If you had `child = RecursiveField(read_only = True)` the code would be:

```
class RecursiveField(serializers.Serializer):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        serializer = self.parent.__class__(value, context=self.context)
        return serializer.data
```

To make it simple, when you (or DRF) calls `serialializer_instance.data`, it makes a call to `to_representation` to serialize the object instance.

Recursion comes into play when doing the `SystmSerializer.to_representation`:

1. when `to_representation(instance)` is called, it will call `to_representation(field_instance)` on every field.
2. One of these fields is the `recursiveField`, and more exactly the [ListSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer) associated with the the `recursiveField`
3. Calling `to_representation` on the [ListSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer) will call `recursiveField.to_representation(child)` for all children (if any) of the instance.
4. This is when recursion starts: the implementation of `recursiveField.to_representation` instanciates a new `SystmSerializer` instance on the child `Systm` object and then calls `SystmSerializer.data` which itself triggers a `to_representation` call... and you are back to step 1 with a new `SystmSerializer` instance on the child `Systm` object.

Recursion ends when there are no children. Of course, you can run into endless recursion if a child references an ancestor.

Comment: This is basically correct, although pretty simplified and I am not sure i its going to help the OP actually understand what is going on underneath all that rest framework magic.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for the reply! However I am afraid Michael is right, I dont see the whole picture yet. I dont get it how the recursion comes into picture, why is there recursion at all? Is it because the to_represantation(...) is called for every record of the queryset by django?

Comment: Added a simplified description how recursion occurs, hope this helps. The to_representation is indeed called on the object instance and on all the children, and so on...